# How to change context in WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am developing my first WPF application using MVVM for some sort of Kiosk in fullscreen. 
I need to change the context (video view, text view, powerpoint view) in response to an asynchronous event.

I'm having a hard time because I have defined the following data contexts in MVVM but I haven't yet been able to switch between them:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:VideoViewModel}">
        <v:VideoView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:PowerpointViewModel}">
        <v:PowerpointView />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually I have a `ShellViewModel` which contains a `CurrentPage` property which contains the ViewModel of the current page. In the XAML I'll bind a `ContentControl.Content` to the `CurrentPage`, and then to switch the View, I just switch the CurrentPage property to whatever ViewModel should be current.

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentPage}" />
```

Change Page Command:

```
void ChangePage(ViewModelBase page)
{
    CurrentPage = page;
}
```

For an example, see [this post](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/28/switching-between-viewsusercontrols-using-mvvm/) of mine